# Will three pairs of 12' 2x4 lumber provide a safe work platform for one person?

Tags: flooring

I need to build a temp. floor over my basement steps which is a 9' opening, so I can do ceiling repairs where an old chimney pipe was pulled long ago. If I fasten 6- 2x4x12 together in pairs and place them on the side with plywood on top, how much weight can it support? Would a 200 lb man be safe to work on that structure

---

No I am asking if 6- 12ft two by fours fastened in pairs sitting on their sides for more strength, not laying flat or stacked, under a piece of 8' long by 3'wide plywood spanning over top of a 9 foot open stairwell held at each end by over lapping the existing upper floor, would it be strong enough to hold the person without breaking and dropping them 15 extra foot down the basement steps which would then be under the newly built temp floor area. The person will be trying to reach the ceiling on the upper 2nd floor for repairs. That 2nd floor ceiling is over the top of the basement stairwell opening. I don't believe ladders coming up out of the basement on steps would be any safer then building a temp floor piece over top of the stair opening on the 2nd floor. The question was would double 2x4's hold the weight of a man reaching up over his head toward the 2nd floor ceiling to work and not drop him down two stories? How much load could be safely held up by 6 pieces of wood/plywood?  I am simply building a removable floor section. Can you picture a floor laying on top of an existing floor at each end while there is a 9 ft long opening under this 12ft floor piece?

Comment: I can't picture what you're describing at all - a picture would help a lot.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @batsplatsterson is right: adding a picture or diagram to your post would really help.

Comment: I think I understand this, but I don't know if it is good enough or not (I think it is, but not sure) so a comment rather than an answer: 8' x 3' plywood. Supporting the long (8') are 6 12' long 2x4s. There is a 9' gap for the stairwell, so the 12' 2x4s will be able to rest approx. 1.5' on the existing floor around the stairwells on each end. The 6 2x4s will be in pairs, so that is 3 pairs supporting a 3' wide plywood (e.g., one pair near each edge and one in the middle). 200lb man, tools, etc. on top of the plywood working.

Answer (score 1):

### Long story short: don't do it.

Some of the most dangerous words you'll ever hear:  "Aww, that ain't going nowhere."  Over the years I have seen a lot of mishaps with homebuilt contraptions.

I am still not super clear even after you added to your description, I get the gist but **the details are very important** and you're way short on details for my taste.  It sounds like you're building a scaffold or temporary floor over your basement opening to work on the ceiling above.  You're going to build it with doubled 2x4 joists spanning 9'.  Assuming the width of the stairwell is about 3' they'll be about 18" apart.

In construction you usually use span tables to determine the distance you can span with lumber.  You can do engineering calculations but that's a lot more work, and error prone.  Your scaffold / temporary floor won't be constructed like a real permanent floor so they don't really apply, but they still shed some light.  Here's a link to some span tables, they are not hard to find online:

https://up.codes/s/allowable-ceiling-joist-spans

Now 2x4's are never used as floor joists any more, so the span tables for floor joists don't help, they start at 2x6's.  However 2x4's are still used for ceiling joists, and ceiling joists support attic floors.  The span tables for an attic with limited storage allow right around 9' of span for 2x4's spaced 16" on center, depending on the grade of wood.  So with doubled 2x4's, I really don't think a 200 pound man on a ladder is going to snap them.

However I still think it's a bad idea because I don't think snapping the lumber is the main danger here.  I think the most likely trouble is fastening this temporary floor / scaffold to the permanent structure securely and safely.  You haven't discussed this at all.  **With the heights involved just about any accident that happens will be a serious accident, so I would not attempt this.**

If you google "stairway ladder" and "stairway scaffold" you'll see that there are lots of options available to do this kind of work without trying to build something yourself.

Comment: I had much the same idea myself, but not the specifics of where to look for joist spans. I also noticed that there was no mention of how the contraption would attach to the existing structure - there are ways to do it that would be quite secure, and some ways that would not...

Answer (score 1):

My back porch roof is 10' long and framed with 2*4s on 16" centers, I had to do a bunch of work up there when I first bought the place because a tree fell on it. I weigh about 225lb, didn't have any problems besides not really wanting to be up there. Just make sure the framing is sound, and add supports perpendicular to the 2*4s so they won't want to roll. Probably best to anchor it to something that won't move, either.

Comment: I agree. A 12' plank with three 4x4 rails would be plenty strong for one person.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if a 9' sheet of plywood can span 7'6" if supported by 9" of built-up 2x4s on both sides? No that is not safe. You need to put floor joists under the plywood, probably something like 1-2x4 at 12" on center spacing.